# Override c++-mode font lock

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, c++, cc-mode

I am improving the C++ highlighting in Emacs with the minor mode: [modern-cpp-font-lock](https://github.com/ludwigpacifici/modern-cpp-font-lock).

Consider this following C++14 code:

```
int main() { int i = 1'2'3l; }
```

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

> Optional single quotes(') may be inserted between the digits as a
>   separator. They are ignored by the compiler.

In modern-cpp-font-lock, I set `1'2'3` to `font-lock-constant-face` and I set the integer suffix `l` to `font-lock-keyword-face`.

In `fundamental-mode` and `modern-c++-font-lock-mode` activated, I see the expected result. However, with `c++-mode` and `modern-c++-font-lock-mode` activated, `'2'` is highlighted as a string (`l` is correctly font locked).

I know the highlighting rely on the principle "first come first served" - meaning rules will not apply on words already highlighted.

Do you know if it is possible to override font-lock of a major mode? Or is it possible to change the order of rules to apply the font-lock (for example, longer rules first)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font-lock use two phases:

- The syntactic phase. In this phase, Emacs determines things like strings and comments.
- The keyword phase, i.e. the normal font-lock rules.

If you want to make Emacs ignore single quotes in digits, you have to do this in the first phase. Effectively, you will have to supply a custom `syntax-propertize-function`, which should set a suitable `syntax-table` text property on the quote character.

See [this article](http://www.lunaryorn.com/2014/06/16/advanced-syntactic-fontification.html) on how to do this. Link broken, [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20150627183737/https://www.lunaryorn.com/2014/06/16/advanced-syntactic-fontification.html).

Just remember that if you install your own syntax-propertize-function in a minor mode, you still have to ensure that the original function is executed.

Also, I've noticed that there is some work being done on modern C++ on the Emacs master branch, maybe this has already been handled there.

Comment: Yes there is some work done on the Emacs master branch. I send [emails](https://sourceforge.net/p/cc-mode/mailman/message/35142472/) to the maintainer of cc-mode for bugs (single quotes in integers for example). However the release cycle on Emacs is too long (the fix in cc-mode won't be included in Emacs 25). That's why I provide this extended font-lock.

Comment: Please include answer instead of links... which are now broken.

Comment: @ideasman42, I agree that a full answer would be better. However, it would require quite some time to write such an answer -- time I currently don't have. Anyway, someone seems to have fixed the link, so I just leave it as it is for now.