# Define new comment style with string literals rather than characters

Tags: regular-expressions, syntax-highlighting, comment, syntax-table

I am trying to define another comment style, similar to what we can do with [`modify-syntax-entry`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Table-Functions.html#index-modify_002dsyntax_002dentry):

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?/ ". 124b")
(modify-syntax-entry ?* ". 23")
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n "> b")
```

However, the comment has to be as follows:

```
`comment("This is my comment!")`
```

I have tried using regex:

```lisp
(defconst my-comment-macro-regexp
   (rx "`comment(\"" (zero-or-more anything) "\")`"))

(defconst my-font-lock-keywords
  (list
   (cons my-comment-macro-regexp 'font-lock-comment-face)))
```

But this doesn't work as the string highlighting on the inside of the macro takes precedence over this font style.

Comment: Did you mean to include the backticks in the "this is my comment" bit? The four-space indent already marks it as a code block; the backticks do inline code.

I think you do, but wanted to clarify because we have Markdown syntax and emacs lisp syntax possibly clashing here...

Comment: @DanDrake yep, the single backticks are to be included.  Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to override the string matching:

```lisp
(defconst my-font-lock-keywords
  (list
   (list my-comment-macro-regexp 0 'font-lock-comment-face t)))
```

You can read a good explanation on why this works here: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107675/12069968).

See also: [[2]](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61891/25429), [[3]](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24108/25429).